# option in select tag is not getting appended in jquery

Tags: jquery

The option attribute in select tag below is not getting appended on page load. Below is the code that i have used. I dont know what is the problem that i am facing.

```
<select id="cuisineList" style="width: 200px;height: 30px;"></select>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    selectValues = { "1": "test1", "2": "test2" }

       var options = '';
       $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
           options += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
        });

       $("#cuisineList").append(options);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$(document).ready(function(){})` to ensure you document is loaded before you run your jQuery code.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectValues = {
    "1": "test1",
    "2": "test2"
  }

  var options = '';
  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
  });

  $("#cuisineList").append(options);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cuisineList" style="width: 200px;height: 30px;"></select>
```

Comment: damm. How did i missed it..Thank you Andersen it works.

Comment: @ManojStack No problem, happy to help